# How can I change the background color specifically for full screen view?

Tags: highcharts, background, fullscreen

Normally I show the highchart graphs on my website with a **transparent background**.
My website has a white background with an very light colored image in it.

But when I view the graph in **full screen** (exporting.js), it shows it with a **black background**.

Would be perfect if I could indicate that the normal background is transparent but the background in 'view in full screen' mode should be white.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update colour every time when you enable and disable full view. Use chart events `fullscreenOpen` and `fullscreenClose` to achieve that.

```
  chart: {
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    events: {
      fullscreenOpen: function() {
        this.update({
          chart: {
            backgroundColor: 'white'
          }
        })
      },
      fullscreenClose: function() {
        this.update({
          chart: {
            backgroundColor: 'transparent'
          }
        })
      }
    }
  },
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/q8hpeLu3/

**API References:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.fullscreenOpen
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.fullscreenClose